# "No instance of overloaded function" error with static friend template function

Tags: c++, templates, friend-function

I have a class `A` that is trying to call a nonmember function `DoTheThing`. `DoTheThing` is a friend of class `A` so that it can call a private member function `TheThing` of `A`. `DoTheThing` is a template function so that it can call `TheThing` in multiple user-defined classes. Because the error references an overloaded function, I believe that I am redefining `DoTheThing` within `A`, but I cannot figure out how to fix this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Component>
    requires requires (std::vector<double>& vec, int i) {Component::TheThing(vec, i); }
    static void DoTheThing(std::vector<double>& vec, int i) {
        Component::TheThing(vec, i);
    }


class A {
    template<class Component>
    friend void DoTheThing(std::vector<double>& vec, int i);
public:
    A() {
        vec_.resize(10, 5);
        DoTheThing<A>(vec_, 7); // Error: no instance of overloaded function
    }
private:
    static void TheThing(std::vector<double>& vec, int i) {
        vec[i] = vec[i] * i;
    }


    std::vector<double> vec_;
};
```

Am I redefining `DoTheThing`? How do I make the non-member `DoTheThing` a friend of `A`? How do I call `DoTheThing` in the constructor of `A`?

Comment: `Component::TheThing(vec, i);` is not valid. It's a non-static member function, so you need an object to call it. And even with an object, `TheThing` is private. Also, add the error from the `requires` clause, it's useful.

Comment: @cigien yes, ```TheThing``` was supposed to be static. Shouldn't it be accessible if ```DoTheThing``` is a friend of class A? And also I have no error from the requires clause. Make sure you are using C++20.

Comment: There is definitely an error from the requires clause. That's where the call actually fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not constraining the `friend` declaration with an ad-hoc requires clause, so you are actually not granting friendship to the same `DoTheThing` function you want. You need to replicate the `requires` clause in the `friend` declaration as well:

```
class A {
    template<class Component>
    requires requires (std::vector<double>& vec, int i) {Component::TheThing(vec, i); }
    friend void DoTheThing(std::vector<double>& vec, int i);
// ...
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x3r4Yj).

---

However, you should name this concept, and the usage will be simpler:

```
template<typename Component>
concept CanDoThing = requires (std::vector<double>& vec, int i) { 
  Component::TheThing(vec, i); 
};

template<CanDoThing Component>
static void DoTheThing(std::vector<double>& vec, int i) {
  Component::TheThing(vec, i);
}

class A {
  template<CanDoThing Component>
  friend void DoTheThing(std::vector<double>& vec, int i);
// ...
};
```